# Быстрая сортировка с использованием указателей си

Tags: c, сортировка

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>

void QuickSort(int *a, int size){
    int *left = a; // Адрес 1 элемента
    int *right = a + (size - 1); // Адрес 2 элемента
    int *pivot = a + (size / 2); // Адрес разделителя
    printf("\n");
    printf("pivot %d, l - %d, r - %d\n", *pivot, *left, *right);
    do{
        while(*left < *pivot) ++left; // Разыменовываем, сравниваем значения и сдвигаем указатель
        while(*right > *pivot) --right;
        if(left <= right) { // Меняем местами
            int temp = *left;
            *left = *right;
            *right = temp;
            ++left;
            --right;
        }
    } while(left <= right); // Обходим весь массив
    if(a < right) QuickSort(a, right - a);
    if(left < a + (size - 1)) QuickSort(left, (a + (size - 1)) - left);
}

int main(){
    int b[] = {2,4,67,23,86,34,5,1, 55, 12, 13};
    int *c = b;
    int s = sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);

    
    QuickSort(c, s);

    for(int *p = b; p < b + sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]); p++){
        printf(" %d", *p);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать сортировку Хоара с помощью указателей на си.

Comment: `if(left <= right)` зачем сравниваешь тут указатели?

Comment: Иначе вообще не работает.

Comment: А просто `qsort` не годится?.. Если нет — то что значит "с помощью указателей"? Без них вы это сделать можете?

Comment: Могу. Но пробую реализовать алгоритм сам, работая через адреса массива, и запутался напрочь.)))

Comment: Вы должны вытащить `*pivot` из массива в отдельную переменную и сравнивать `*left` и `*right` с ней (тогда сам этот элемент будет сдвигаться внутри разделяемого массива (что и требуется, а у вас он остается на месте (это ошибка))). Посмотрите на [algorithm partition(A, low, high) is
   pivot:= A\[(low + high) / 2\] ...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Извините, может я неправильно понял, но в функцию я передаю вторым аргументом размер массива, она у меня используется для вычисления крайних элементов. Размер изменяется, значит должно меняться положение разделителя? Если не трудно приведите пример кода, а то глаз уже дергается.